# is 'giving out' a reference to 'this' inside the constructor ok?

Tags: c++

my code :

```
Scene::Scene(const std::string &scene_file) : ambient_light(0, 0, 0), background(0, 0, 0){
  scene_parser parser(*this);
  parser.parse(scene_file);
}
```

scene_parser is a friend of Scene, and in the parse method it accesses(r/w) the members of Scene. Is this going to cause any problems?

Comment: It should be noted somewhere that this is OK so long as you give out the `this` pointer from within the constructor body, and not the initialization list.

Comment: also check what c++faq-lite has to say: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your particular example, no problems should arise.

Generally the problem with giving out `this` references is that the lifetimes of the two objects don't exactly align and the other object could try to access the referred-to object after it has already been destroyed.

In your example, the `scene_parser` object is on the stack, so it's lifetime ends at the end of the `Scene` constructor.  There is no possible way it could attempt to access a non-existent object via that `this` reference you provided, so no problems can arise.

Comment: No, but if `parser` invokes `virtual` functions, you won't get the desired effect. Although that *is* legal, you could (and probably should) consider that a bug.

Comment: That's a potential gotcha with giving out any pointers at all, nothing specific to constructors or the `this` pointer.  The real gotcha with giving away `this` from the constructor is that class member functions could be called before the constructor finishes establishing invariants.

Comment: I don't intend on subclassing Scene, so it seems all is well.

Comment: Also accessing the reference before the constructor completes is probably UB (as before the object is fully constructed is it a real object?). I don;t know just asking. But it is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @Martin:  It's not UB, but Ben's warning about establishing invariants is sage.  The rest (virtual functions not working as expected) is all perfectly well defined, and frequently desired behavior.  My answer was just with respect to his specific question, making a guess about what the scene_parser object was going to do.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's ok to give out a reference to `this`.  However, you usually want to do that when the other object will use the pointer later.  Your use case looks like it will use the `Scene` immediately, before the constructor completes, which is a very slippery slope.

Right now, you're not establishing any invariants after calling `parse`, so it should be ok, but it's also fragile and easy for future changes to introduce breakage.

Comment: Good answer.  I think you should include some of the information you provide in comments to other answers, since it seems there are some subtleties that should be addressed.

Comment: @voodooclock: The caveats related to virtual functions don't actually require handing the `this` pointer to any other object.  You can get into trouble calling the class's own functions from inside the constructor.  Besides, the OP has already indicated that `Scene` is a terminal class, so the dynamic type of the object won't be a problem.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification--I was reading way too much into that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Inside the constructor body (i.e. once the initializer list is executed), the object is considered "fully constructed" up to the current type. Therefore, you *can* reference `*this`, but any `virtual` function calls will not use overrided functions in derived classes.

Comment: I think you got that backwards on the calls to virtual functions, but that is an important thing to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

All of your subobjects (members and bases) are constructed by the first statement in the body of the constructor.  If your object is in a "valid state" (which is part of the definition of your class, sometimes called the "class invariant") at this point, you can treat it as a fully constructed object and do anything with it.  However, virtual lookup does work slightly differently than you may expect or require: if this is a base class (and thus this object is a subobject of something else), the final type hasn't been "assigned" yet.  For example, this is one way to call pure-virtual methods and get a runtime error (if those methods don't have definitions, anyway).

A more interesting situation is using *this* in the constructor initializer; that does have some caveats, but that is also before the constructor body.